# How do you disable scrolling? I want my app to be displayed on full screen

Tags: ios, iphone

I have been designing a app on xcode over the past week but I have encountered a problem. When I run the app on iPhone simulators (3.5 inch and 4 inch) my game is scrollable when it shouldn't be. I want my app to be displayed on full screen of iPhone with no scrolling.

I have not changed any of the settings in storyboard so I am starting to think maybe its a problem with the simulator?

Anyone have any ideas of what's wrong and how I could correct this? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: When is it not scrollable? Show a picture of the storyboard. Have you setup the auto-layout constraints?

Comment: Can you provide more details? What kinds of views are you using in your interface? When you say full screen, are you saying you would also like to hide the status bar? Please share some screenshots and/or code.

Comment: Its a single view based application. I am not using webView, or scrollview, I am just using 4 small image views on the view Controller. Im on a macBook Pro. The photo won't show much. Basicaly the simulator is displaying the app almost as if it is zoomed in(im not really sure whats wrong). To see the whole game you have to scroll down, which obviously, i do not want.

Comment: Don't worry about it. It's just because the screen resolution on your Mac isn't setup probably for the simulator. Try on a device when the pixels will be correct. It's not an issue with the simulator even it just because of pixel density being high on iphone and the Mac screen not handling it very well.

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty vague (how are you "designing" the game? With SpriteKit? UIKit?) but here is some reading material that should get you pointed in the right direction:
- [AutoLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Autosizing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just an issue with the simulator.  It seems like if the resolution of the screen is below a certain amount, it shrinks the simulator window to fit, and then you have to scroll around inside the simulator to see the whole VIEW.  I noticed this issue because my Macbook has a small screen.  But when running on an actual device, it takes up the whole screen as it should.  You could try using different simulated devices with smaller screens to see if it still does it.